Pod not created with Helm chart
Summary:
I am new to Helm and I am trying out some basic commands on my workstation but I am unable to deploy via Helm charts.
Setup:
I am using microk8s v1.31 and helm v3.16.2. I have repeatedly ran the microk8s status command just to see if it is indeed running. I am running a single control-plane node.
Description:
I started with using the following commands
helm create foo
helm install dummy foo

I see following output:
NAME: dummy
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Oct 18 15:59:44 2024
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
NOTES:...

However I don't see any pods in my default namespace when I run kubectl get pods.
On running kubectl get deployments I get the following output:
NAME        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
dummy-foo   0/1     0            0           7m38s

Naturally, I had a look at the logs and running kubectl log deployments.app/dummy-foo, I get the output:
error: watch closed before UntilWithoutRetry timeout

I haven't been able to make much progress in understanding this error. Any leads or suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Please share the result of the command kubectl get events

The output to the command is: No resources found in default namespace.

okay, added an answer. There should be some information in kubectl describe deployment <dummy-foo> output

Okay, so it turns out the issue was related to microk8s and not helm. I went to the troubleshooting page for microk8s:https://microk8s.io/docs/troubleshooting#heading--common-issues.
The following command was useful:
sudo microk8s inspect.
The command gave an error of the following form:
...
Inspecting dqlite   
   Inspect dqlite
cp: cannot stat '/var/snap/microk8s/7229/var/kubernetes/backend/localnode.yaml': No such file or directory

I came across this discussion on github: https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/4361
I tried the solution provided by one of the users(specifically: https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/4361#issuecomment-2200521421)
Note that the yaml file should be formatted as:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: localnode-config
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  address: 192.168.1.100:19001
  role: node

I ran the microk8s inspect command again and there were no errors.
Subsequently, I re ran all the helm commands I tried earlier and now I can see the pod and the deployment in the default namespace.
kubectl get deployments
NAME        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
dummy-foo   1/1     1            1           129m

kubectl get pods
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
dummy-foo-6566f5f7b9-7d7b2   1/1     Running   1 (6m55s ago)   51m


There are no ready pods of the app. To get more information about the root cause you can use kubectl describe deployment <dummy-foo> command

Sorry, for the sake of brevity I did not post the output from the describe deployment command in my original question, but what I noticed was that again for Replicas  there was 1 Desired and the rest (available, updated, etc.) were all zero. Under Events I have the output <None>, so I don't really follow why Helm is saying it was deployed whereas in reality no such thing happened.

Did you try to upgrade helm?

I am using v3.16.2 which as far as I know is the latest version.

Sorry, you’re right

Your deployment is not successful. READY is still 0/1.
Please use the following command to debug the issue further and provide more details
Kubectl get events

Yes, I had an inkling that the deployment did not go through, however, I can't make sense of the error that I received from the logs (stated at the end of my original question).
kubectl get events on the default namespace does not detect any resources.

Nice! thanks for sharing
